# cohomology of dual intersection complex of a k3 surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, hodge-theory

Let $\Delta \subset \mathbb{C}$ be a small  disc and let $f: X \to \Delta$ be a flat morphism of complex manifolds such that $X_t$ is a smooth K3 surface for $t \neq 0$, and $X_0$ is an snc divisor. Denote the irreducible components of $X_0$ as $(V_i), 1 \leq i \leq n$ and $C_{i,j} = V_i \cap V_j$.  In the paper of Vik. S. Kulikov ["Degenerations of K3 surfaces and Enriques surfaces"](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=im&paperid=1877&option_lang=eng), Corollary 2.8 states 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n h^{2,0}(V_i) + \dfrac{1}{2}\mathrm{dim\,Coker} (\oplus H^1(V_i) \to \oplus_{i < j} H^1(C_{i,j}) + h^2(\Pi(X_0)) =  1
$$
where the cokernel is taken of the morphism that is the alternate sum of restriction morphisms, and $\Pi(X_0)$ is the dual intersection complex. In the paper this corallary is obtained following examination of the mixed Hodge structure on $X_0$ and the Clemens-Schmid exact sequences that relate it to the limit mixed Hodge structure on the cohomology of the nearby fibre.

It is remarked after the Corollary that it can be obtained without using the Clemens-Schmid exact sequences. My question is to what kind of proof does this remark point?

Comment: I have no idea what the answer is, but you may want to look at papers by Miranda, Friedman, and Morrison.  They wrote a lot about degenerations of K-3 surfaces.